# Resign keyboard immediately after button press

Tags: iphone, ios, xml-rpc

I have a button, "getResponse", that makes a XMLRPC call to a server after you put in an IP address in a UITextField. Id like the "getResponse" button to first resign the keyboard if its up THEN make the call to the server.

As it is now, if the keyboard is up, it will make the call to the server, retrive the info or the error if no valid server found, THEN resign the keyboard.

I know its probably something very easy but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Any help would be great, thanks!

**Code:**

**h.**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XMLRPCResponse.h"
#import "XMLRPCRequest.h"
#import "XMLRPCConnection.h"


@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UILabel *helloResponse;
    IBOutlet UILabel *SumCountsResponse;
    IBOutlet UITextField *serverInput;
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *pickerTrap;
    IBOutlet UIAlertView *alert;

    NSMutableArray * pickerViewArray;

    int trapSelected;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *helloResponse; 
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *SumCountsResponse;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *serverInput;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *pickerTrap;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIAlertView *alert;



- (IBAction)getResponse:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)serverInputReturn:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender;


@end
```

**m.**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize helloResponse;
@synthesize SumCountsResponse;
@synthesize serverInput;
@synthesize pickerView;
@synthesize pickerTrap;
@synthesize alert;


-(IBAction)serverInputReturn:(id)sender { //resign keyboard on 'return' button

    [sender resignFirstResponder];

}

-(IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender { //resign keyboard on background touch

    [serverInput resignFirstResponder];
}


-(IBAction)getResponse: (id) sender {

    [self serverInputReturn:self]; //trying to call method to resign keyboard first 

    //setup IP call for XMLserver
    NSString *server = serverInput.text;
    NSString *http = @"http://";
    server = [server stringByAppendingString:@":8080/RPC2"];
    server = [http stringByAppendingString:server];

    //Begin calls to XMLRPC server for data return
    XMLRPCRequest *requestHello = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithHost:[NSURL URLWithString:server]];
    [requestHello setMethod:@"hello" withObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil]];
    NSString *resultHello = [self executeXMLRPCRequest:requestHello];
    [requestHello release];


    XMLRPCRequest *requestSumCounts = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithHost:[NSURL URLWithString:server]];
    [requestSumCounts setMethod:@"SumCountsString" withObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil]];
    NSString *resultSumCounts = [self executeXMLRPCRequest:requestSumCounts];
    [requestSumCounts release];


    XMLRPCRequest *requestTrapCountX = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithHost:[NSURL URLWithString:server]];
    [requestTrapCountX setMethod:@"TrapCountString" withObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:trapSelected], nil]];
    NSString *resultTrapCountX = [self executeXMLRPCRequest:requestTrapCountX];
    [requestTrapCountX release];


    if (![resultHello isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
            alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error: Invalid Server Address" message:@"Please Check Server Address and Try Again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
    }
    else{
        helloResponse.text = resultHello;
        SumCountsResponse.text = resultSumCounts;
        pickerTrap.text = resultTrapCountX;

    }
    }
}


- (id)executeXMLRPCRequest:(XMLRPCRequest *)req {
    XMLRPCResponse *userInfoResponse = [XMLRPCConnection sendSynchronousXMLRPCRequest:req];
    if ([userInfoResponse isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        return alert;
    }
    else{
    return [userInfoResponse object];
    }
}
```

Comment: need more info. what is happening? what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: The button is executing code that makes a call to an XMLRPC server. I first put in an IP address in a UITextBox, then press the getResponse IBAction. I want it to FIRST resign the keyboard, THEN call the XMLRPC server and show the data. As it is now, the server is first called, then the data comes through, then the keyboard resigns.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
[self serverInputReturn:self];
```

Try

```
[self serverInputReturn:self.serverInput];
```

You need to pass the UITextField not the UIViewController.

Make sure that you are setting the UITextField's delegate to the UIViewController via

```
self.serverInput.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Nope, still works the same: press getResponse, calls server, gets info, then releases the keyboard...

Comment: Can you try directly, [self.serverInput resignFirstResponder]?

Comment: Also check if serverInput is indeed the firstResponder, via serverInput.isFirstResponder

Comment: added: 'if(serverInput.isFirstResponder){ [self.serverInput resignFirstResponder];}' But still does the same thing...

Comment: I am sorry. First of all..please use self.serverInput. not serverInput. Secondly, does the code go into the if statement? Can you run in debugmode?

Comment: Also did you hookup your UIButton with this getResponse method? Where is the button defined. dont see in .h file.

Comment: More thoughts, did you declare, the textField's delegate? self.serverInput.delegate = self;

Comment: Yes the code goes into the if statement. Yes, the UIButton is hooked up to getResponse. I believe this is the correct declaration from the .h: `- (IBAction)getResponse:(id)sender;` No the textFileds delegate is not declared... I will do that. This is the code snippet now. But still works the same. `-(IBAction)getResponse: (id) sender {
    
    self.serverInput.delegate = self;
    
    if (self.serverInput.isFirstResponder) {
        [self.serverInput resignFirstResponder];`

Comment: Ok so thats the issue. self.serverInput.delegate = self needs to be done in viewDidLoad. Not in the getResponse method.

Comment: Added the correct declaration for the button in the .h. `IBOutlet UIButton *getResponse;` `@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *getResponse;`

Comment: Added some NSLogs. Console (shortened a bit): `2011-08-12 16:16:25.665 IPM Solutions[10926:207] yes its first responder
2011-08-12 16:16:25.668 supposed to resign keyboard here
2011-08-12 16:16:25.669 finished setting up server address
2011-08-12 16:16:25.669 requesting requestHello
2011-08-12 16:16:25.670 exectuting XMLRPCRequest
2011-08-12 16:16:27.780 requesting requestSumCounts
2011-08-12 16:16:27.780 exectuting XMLRPCRequest
2011-08-12 16:16:29.784 requesting requestTrapCountX
2011-08-12 16:16:29.784 exectuting XMLRPCRequest
2011-08-12 16:16:31.788 at if for String Class`